# How to get the index of a sorted list which has reoccurring numbers

Tags: list, sorting

I have a list, say [2,3,3,4], I want to return the index of the list as [0, 1, 1, 3]. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into `np.argsort`?

Comment: Yeah, it doe not give same index to repetitive numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `np.unique` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = [2, 3, 3, 4]
b = [0, 1, 1, 3]

us, inds, inv = np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

res = inds[inv]

assert (b == res).all()
```